# Heroku: stop all one-off dynos without dyno name

Tags: heroku, command-line, dyno

I run the following command twice to start my two one-off dynos

```
heroku run:detached python main.py
```

and then stop it using

```
heroku ps:stop <dyno-name>
```

however, I wish to stop all my dynos without knowing dyno names before hand, since I am trying to automate turning on and off my dynos using crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a python script to achieve the same, not that optimised but does the job.

```py
import os

path = 'cd <path-to-project>'

def stop():
    online_ps = os.popen(path + ' && heroku ps').read()
    for ps in online_ps.split():
        if(ps.startswith('run')): # process name example run.1234
            os.system(path + ' && heroku ps:stop ' + ps)

def start():
    os.system(path + ' && heroku run:detached python main.py <arg1>') # dyno 1
    os.system(path + ' && heroku run:detached python main.py <arg2>') # dyno 2

stop()
start()
```

Note:

- mind the spaces in the command
- this code works on the assumption that each process name starts with `run` like `run.1234`